# iOS11 UIToolBar Contentview

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, ios11

In `iOS 11` buttons and text field are unresponsive being subviews of `UIToolBar`. Comparing view hierarchy to `iOS 10` we see there is a `_UIToolBarContentView` over all subview of `UIToolBar`.

For instance, this new layout of the `UIToolBar` breaks `slacktextviewcontroller`
https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController/issues/604

Need a solution working in `iOS 10/11`.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Its weird but I experienced same issue but some case its not visible

Comment: I tried editing the question for you to take it out of closed status. The mods rejected my edits because I included an answer in the edits. They said I should just answer the question. I CAN'T answer the question if it is closed. Anyway, you should override the `layoutSubviews` method of your `UIToolBar` and either bring your unresponsive views to the front or send the last view to the back inside of that override.

Comment: This is actually very good question. No reason to be closed. It's takes time and research to find out the difference between iOS 10/11. Thanks for that

Comment: I run into the same issue, too.I think the question is clear enough to state the issue.We should reopen this question

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To solve the problem for `iOS11` (compatible with lower versions) you only need
to make `layoutSubview` right after `UIToolBar` was added as a subview to UI hierarchy.

In this case `_UIToolbarContentView` lowers to the first subview of UIToolBar, and you can
add all your subviews higher as before.

For example in `ObjC`,

```
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
    [self addSubview: toolbar];
    [toolbar layoutIfNeeded];

    <here one can add all subviews needed>
```

The same problem happens with [slacktextviewcontroller](https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController/issues/604#issuecomment-332513940)

Comment: What if we added the views in a interface builder ? any other solution other than send them to front ?

Comment: Thank you. Was facing the same problem.

Comment: I have added UIToolBar using storyboard, how do I solve this issue.

Comment: @anamika41 When I try to add a textField or button into toolbar via xib, the element is automatically wrapped in BarButtonItem. So I have touch access to these element, also one can check that toolbarContentView is below these elements at work. Also if I add a button on viewDidLoad into toolbar from xib it also works fine on touch.

Comment: My UIToolbar is part of a storyboard. The UIToolbar and its children (buttons) are referenced in a view controller. I'm unable to access them because at runtime they are obscured by `_UIToolbarContentView` I'm not sure how I should handle it. I'm not using a xib nor creating it in code.

Comment: I have a view controller that uses a toolbar as its view. The solution in this answer worked for me up to iOS 12 and stopped working with iOS 13. My new solution is to override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and invoke `bringSubviewToFront:()` on the toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem in my case. I rewrite the `layoutSubviews` method in subclass of UIToobar and change the `userInteractionEnable` of `_UIToolbarContentView` into NO.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];


    NSArray *subViewArray = [self subviews];

    for (id view in subViewArray) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:(NSClassFromString(@"_UIToolbarContentView"))]) {
            UIView *testView = view;
            testView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
         }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `hitTest(_:with:)` method.

1. First, create a property `contentView` in `UIToolbar`:

   ```
   open private(set) var contentView: UIView = UIView()
   ```
2. Then, make the `contentView`'s frame the same as the `UIToolbar`'s. For example:

   ```
   contentView.frame = bounds
   contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
   addSubview(contentView)
   ```
3. Finally, override the `hitTest(_:with:)` method:

   ```
   open override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
       if self.point(inside: point, with: event) {
           if let hitTestView = contentView.hitTest(point, with: event) {
               return hitTestView
           } else {
               return self
           }
       } else {
           return nil
       }
   }
   ```

In this situation, if you want to customize a toolbar by simply adding additional views, you should **add them to the `contentView`** so they will be positioned appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The new `UIToolbar` object actively uses layout based on constraints, so it is better to override `- (void)updateConstraints` method. To present custom views over `UIToolbar` object it is better to subclass it and add custom container view:

```
- (UIView *)containerView
{
    if (_containerView) {
        return _containerView;
    }
    _containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    _containerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    return _containerView;
}
```

Now you can safely add your custom views to the container view. To make the custom views responsive we need change the order of toolbar subviews after the constraints update:

```
- (void)updateConstraints
{
    [super updateConstraints];

    [self bringSubviewToFront:self.containerView];
}
```

Note, that if you are using `UINavigationController` with custom toolbar, you should force it to update its layout before adding your custom subviews.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift with autolayout and code only, what worked for me was to do layout as [malex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46448751/4691224) mentions just before adding items, but after setting constraints.

- Instantiate your toolbar
- Add it to your view
- Add constraints

  toolbar.layoutIfNeeded()

  toolbar.setItems([... (your items)], animated: true)

Answer (score -2):

There is an odd way to do it.

```
[self.textInputbar sendSubviewToBack:[self.textInputbar.subviews lastObject]];
```

Comment: What is "textInputbar" ?

Comment: The textInputbar is an object of UIToolbar.

Comment: It is the solution described at [github](https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController/issues/604)

Comment: Why be in context of `SlackTextViewController` only, it's a general problem related to `UIToolBar`. Anyway, it doesn't solve the issue even if I bring the `lastObject` to front

Comment: @gran33 Please see the working fix below. I've got the same issue.